# Save Javascript Array in Database (Bootstrap Table)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a bootstrap table in this fashion:

```
//Document Ready
$(function() {
    var $proj_table = $("#project-table");

    //Load Table
    $proj_table.editable.defaults.url = "php/save.php";
    create_table($proj_table, "php/sql_data.php", [{
        checkbox: true
    }, {
        field: "ID",
        title: "ID",
        sortable: true
    }, {
        field: "project",
        title: "Project",
        editable: {
            title: "Project",
            placeholder: "Project"
        }
    }, {
        field: "owner",
        title: "Owner",
        editable: {
            title: "Owner",
            placeholder: "Owner"
        }
    }, {
        field: "name_1",
        title: "Name #1",
        editable: {
            title: "Name #1",
            placeholder: "Name #1"
        }
    }, {
        field: "name_2",
        title: "Name #2",
        editable: {
            title: "Name #2",
            placeholder: "Name #2"
        }
    }, {
        field: "status",
        title: "Status",
        editable: {
            title: "Status",
            type: "select",
            source: [
                {value: 0, text: "Not Selected"},
                {value: 1, text: "Not Started"},
                {value: 2, text: "WIP"},
                {value: 3, text: "Completed"}
            ],
            display: function(value, sourceData) {
                var colors     = {0: "Gray", 1: "#E67C73", 2: "#F6B86B", 3: "#57BB8A"};
                var status_ele = $.grep(sourceData, function(ele){ return ele.value == value; });

                $(this).text(status_ele[0].text).css("color", colors[value]);
            },
            showbuttons: false
        }
    }], "ID");

    //Button Listeners
    $("#new-row").click(function() {
        new_row($proj_table, "php/new_row.php");
    });

    $("#delete-rows").click(function() {
        delete_rows($proj_table, "php/delete_rows.php", "post");
    });
});

//Function Definitions
function create_table(table, url, columns, idField)
{
    table.bootstrapTable({
        url: url,
        columns: columns,
        idField: idField
    });
}

function delete_rows(table, url, method) {
    var $selected_rows = table.bootstrapTable("getSelections");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: {
            selected_rows: $selected_rows
        }
    });

    table.bootstrapTable("refresh");
}

function new_row(table, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url
    });

    table.bootstrapTable("refresh");
}
```

Now you can see one blatantly obvious problem, I have hardcoded the columns parameter to the point where it is 50% of my entire code. I also want to be able to add columns, so having columns coded like this is not possible.

Now what I want to be able to do is be able to store this array in some sort of database. And retrieve that data when this table is created.

Now storing in this in a JSON format is kinda hard, because the way that bootstrap organizes is this: [OBJECT OBJECT, OBJECT] not ["a": OBJECT, "b": OBJECT, "c": OBJECT] as a normal JSON format would do.

Another reason why I want to be able to store this is I want to be able to append more objects so I that I can view more columns.

So at the end of day I want:
1. Store javascript array (or some variant that I can covert to javascript array) in database;
2. Be able to append to javascript array in database
3. Be able to retrieve data to be able to create data.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what data do you want to store in a database?

Comment: @Noface Specifically the array in my create_table function call, can't miss it.

Comment: You *can* consider an array as JSON. However you will not be able to save the function inside the last object in the database.

You need need convert the JSON to a format that the sql database will want. Check out https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql Send that array through xhr ($.ajax) or fetch as a string.

You can serialize JSON into a string with `JSON.stringify()` and parse it back from the server with `JSON.parse()`

Your question is too broad to answer or you are not telling us what is confusing you.

Comment: @Noface Updated post to clarify things up